# Can a iOS App to send interrupt to itself?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avaudioplayer

I am new to iOS development and looking for some help. I am wondering if an iOS app can send interrupt to itself?

In particular i want to send a `mediaServicesWereResetNotification` to app to force a hard reset. Please suggest if it is possible.  As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616540-mediaserviceswereresetnotificati) this notification can be triggered by force fully restart media server on device. I want to check if I can just get the notification on my app without restart.

Comment: what do mean ` hard reset`?

Comment: @SPatel what I meant is that on getting this interrupt application reinitialize audio objects.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a 'hard reset'.

As the documentation says, the iOS Settings app has an option to manually trigger this event (as many times you like):

> You can trigger a media server reset by choosing the “Reset Media Services” selection under the Developer menu in the iOS Settings app. Using this utility helps to ensure that your app responds appropriately if media services were reset.

[image]

Comment: As title of question says, I just want to send the interrupt to my app & not really reset media server.

Comment: @vikrant Did you try to setup a listener to `mediaServicesWereResetNotification` and then send that notification yourself?